# exporting users from facebook vai count and offset

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-apps-script

am using Appsscript to fetch users from facebook workplace, my following script works fine, but it gives me default 100 users on first page, i need to understand how to get to page 2, 3 and so on till the time all the users are fetched.

facebook api get all users document says-:

Getting All Users

You can retrieve the information about your users:

Send a GET request to the endpoint https://www.facebook.com/scim/v1/Users}
By default, a GET request on /Users will return results in pages of 100
You can specify a different page size and page offset by including the parameters count and startIndex.

```
GET /scim/v1/Users?count=10&startIndex=20 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.facebook.com
Authorization: Bearer {your access token}
```

my google apps script is as follows-:

```
  function wP() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("WP")
      sheet.clear()
      var token = hided token value

     var url = "https://www.facebook.com/scim/v1/Users?"
     var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{

     headers: {
       'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,

     }
     }))


    var items = response.Resources

    Logger.log(response)
     if (items){

       for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
       var item = items[i]

       sheet.appendRow([item.userName])
       }
      }

   }
```

thank you